# Error when installing Grpc-js, recently, states `bug in node-pre-gyp install fall back...`?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, grpc, grpc-node

**Recent Error when trying to start up a project and install the node client for GRPC**

Command:
npm install --save grpc

```
    > grpc@1.24.2 install C:\Users\pl73003\WebstormProjects\grpc\examples\node\node_modules\grpc
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

    node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Completion callback never invoked!
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\pl73003\\WebstormProjects\\grpc\\examples\\node\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=
    static_library"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\pl73003\WebstormProjects\grpc\examples\node\node_modules\grpc
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
    node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
    node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
    npm WARN grpc-examples@0.1.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN grpc-examples@0.1.0 No license field.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 6
    npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
    npm ERR! Exit status 6
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**I tried changing my grpc version, adding node-pre-gyp as a devDep, building from source....**

Pretty much everything about this error from previous people's answers has not worked.